# What are some clustering algorithms in which I can define no of clusters I require?

Tags: clustering, k-means, hierarchical-clustering, mean-shift

Is there some other clustering algorithms apart from K-means in which I can define no of clusters I require ?I have a data set of large and skewed data points and K-Means is not providing quite satisfying clusters as in K-means two nearer point may end up with completely different clusters depending upon the cluster center points I start with.I want to try some other algorithms in which I can specify no of clusters I require(Not some hierarchical algorithms like mean shift).

Comment: Yes, there are plenty. Have a look at ELKI which probably the largest collection of clustering algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach with k-means is to run multiple times with different initializations, then pick the best. Some other options that let you pick the number of clusters: Gaussian mixture models, agglomerative clustering, various methods based on graph partitioning problems, other k-means-like algorithms (e.g. k-medoids), spectral clustering (which is really just k-means after a nonlinear embedding).